# Spark-submit yarn;client mode, SQLContext.sql returns database not found

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I have used ${SPARK_HOME}/bin/pyspark in console, yarn;client-mode, and the sqlContext could query my hive table however when I used ${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit in yarn;client-mode, the sqlContext could not find the hive database.

Do you know what parameters or files am I missing out?

**How have I defined sqlContext, using Spark 2.1.0:**

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

Comment: Which spark version do you use and how did you define sqlContext ?

Comment: Can you try using HiveContext instead of SQLContext.

Comment: it was the same for HiveContext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From spark 2.0+, We can use SparkSession to access functionality instead of SparkContext,SQLContext,HiveContext(Deprecated in 2.0.0).
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.HiveContext

Try using SparkSession with enableHiveSupport to select hive from ExternalCatalog,

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

Using pyspark console,the context created is hive-aware.In spark-submit,we enable hive with builder.enableHiveSupport(),which sets spark.sql.catalogImplementation=Hive [by default it's in-memory].
For more details, check the links below,

https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-StaticSQLConf.html

Thanks to @Jacek Laskowski

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure why both of them behaved differently, so what I did instead was 
to get sc._conf.getAll() from both spark-submit and pyspark, what I've found amiss for spark-submit was spark.sql.warehouse.dir, spark.sql.catalogImplementation. However like what @Suresh has suggested, it's probably due to the fact of how I've defined sqlContext.